# ruby on rails retain url when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url, submit

I am using devise for user registration but i am facing a problem where when i submit the signup form i get redirected to `/users` but i want to stay on `/signup` where the registration form is...

I achieved it but now i cant see any error messages

my starting form open code

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => signup_path) do |f| %>`

routes

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    post "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post route should point to "devise/registrations#create"